# Chrome loads page scrolled down for Rails app?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm using Bootstrap 3 with Rails 4; only occurring when using Chrome.

After scrolling down on any page and clicking a link from the navbar to visit another page the page is already scrolled down the same amount as it was from the previous page.

For example I scroll down halfway in the about page and click the portfolio link it goes to the portfolio page, but it's already scrolled down the exact same amount as it was before. No JavaScript involved or HTML anchors. I don't know what's causing this as it seems to be only in Chrome.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: probably the turbolink caused this

Comment: @enchante I removed turbolinks and it's still doing the same thing

Comment: @enchante restarting the server was all it took to fix it! Thanks!